# Ocaml Remove Element from List

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm trying to remove given element (x) from a list

```
let rec remove x list =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | var :: tail -> match var with
    | x -> remove x tail
    | _ -> var :: (remove x tail)
;;
```

This is what I've done so far, but when I try

```
remove 5 [1;2;3;4;5]
```

it returns empty list [].

Comment: Did the compiler not give you a warning about an unused branch?

Comment: Yes the compiler warned me but I couldn't understand what it means.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to include it in the question then. It would make it easier us to understand the problem, easier for others to find this question and answer when they encounter the same issue, and the answer could have ben better by explaining the warning properly in context of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `match` is not doing what you think:

```
match var with
    | x -> remove x tail
    | _ -> var :: (remove x tail)
```

The `x` here is a pattern consisting of an identifier (a name). This kind of pattern matches all possible values, and binds the name to the value.

So your pattern is matching all the time, and hence your list is empty.

You can't use a pattern to match against a variable value like `x`. You can only match against fixed values like 3 or None.

You should use an `if` statement to test whether `var` is equal to `x`.